Excel Office Add-in (Office.js) Throws Error When Trying to Read a NamedItem's Range Object on Desktop Excel
The following is a snippet of the code I'm trying to run:
Excel.run(function (context) {
    const startTerm = context.workbook.names.getItem("StartTerm").getRange();
    startTerm.load();
    const endTerm = context.workbook.names.getItem("EndTerm").getRange();
    endTerm.load();
    await context.sync();

    const range = context.workbook.names.getItem("MyRange").getRange();
    range.load("values");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(range.values));
});


For many of my named ranges, this code results in the error "RichApi.Error: This operation is not permitted for the current object." when calling context.sync() on Desktop Excel only.
Excel on the web does not experience any issues with any named ranges, but unfortunately this add-in needs to be able to run through the desktop environment (Windows 10).
To narrow it down slightly, I have two groups of named ranges in my workbook, one point to just single cells, and others point to a range of cells using an OFFSET formula.
The above code works if MyRange has a formula pointing to just a single cell, i.e. "SheetName!$A$10"
But if MyRange has a formula that refers to a range of cells using an OFFSET formula, such as "=OFFSET(SheetName!$E$9,0,0,StartTerm-EndTerm+1,1)", then I receive the error upon trying to load the Excel.Range object, or any property of it when calling context.sync().
StartTerm and EndTerm are both named ranges that point to single cells themselves, and I have already loaded both of them and their values. Considering this works on Excel on the Web I'd like to think there shouldn't be an issue with having nested named range usage like this.
I've tried also loading values via MyRange.arrayValues.values, but while loading arrayValues does not throw an error, both "values" and "type" properties always return as "null" for all OFFSET named ranges. Again works fine for single cell named ranges.
